# Is there a way to find the sibling value of a nested object's property?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-properties

Here's my structure:

```js
var obj = {
  apple: {
     name: "Apple Juice",
     description: "",
  },
  orange: {
     name: "Orange Juice",
     description: "",
  }
}
```

I want to find out the description of `apple` or `orange` by its name without using the parent (`obj.apple.description`)

Is there something like `obj.apple.name.siblingProperty` to get the value of `description` using `name`?

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. I don't quite understand what you are asking for.

Comment: No, because that would be unreliable. The ordering of properties follows specified rules, but you can't do anything about the rules, so depending on the ordering would make for extremely fragile code.

Comment: It will help if you would explain *why* `obj.apple.description` is undesirable.

Comment: There is nothing like that. You could write a helper function to iterate the properties of `obj.apple`, but any solution will be worse than just doing `obj.apple.description`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the object keys, find the index of `name` in that object, then get the next index to get `description`:

```js
var obj = {
  apple: {
     name: "Apple Juice",
     description: "",
  },
  orange: {
     name: "Orange Juice",
     description: "",
  }
}

function getNextKey(object, key) {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);
  var keyIndex = keys.indexOf(key);
  var nextKey = keys[keyIndex + 1];
  console.log(nextKey + ": " + object[nextKey]);
}

getNextKey(obj.apple, "name");
getNextKey(obj.orange, "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use proxy on your object and in the handler just use get function and that's it.now you can do whatever you want. here's my code

```
const obj = {
    apple: {
        name: 'Apple Juice',
        description: 'apple selected',
    },
    orange: {
        name: 'Orange Juice',
        description: 'orange selected',
    },
};

const handler = {
    get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
        return target[prop].description;
    },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, handler);

console.log(proxy.apple);
console.log(proxy.orange);
```